# Google Vision - OCR - Request must specify image and features

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to Implement Google Vision OCR Request. Here is My Code,

```
 func performImageRecognition(image: UIImage){

    //1. Convert Image into base64 encoding
    let imageData: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!
    let encodedString: String = imageData.base64EncodedString()

    //2. Request Body for Vision OCR
    let postBody: [String: Any] = getPOSTBody(base64: encodedString)

    //3. API Call
    AppDelegate.makeRequest(url: Request.url, requestBody: postBody, completionHandler: {
        data, response, error in
        print(error!)

        do{
            let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            print(dictionary)
            self.activityindicator.stopAnimating()
        }catch{
            print("Error Parsing Data: \(error)" )
        }

    })

}

/*
 * Request Body
 */
func getPOSTBody(base64: String) -> [String: Any]{

    let json: [String: Any] = [
        "requests": [["image": ["content": base64]],
                     ["features": [["type": "TEXT_DETECTION"]]]
                    ]
    ]

    return json
}
```

Request Handler

```
class func makeRequest(url: URL, requestBody: [String: Any],completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Int?, String?) -> Void){

    var requestData: Data!
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)

    // 1. Serialize the request body to Data
    do{
        requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestBody, options: [])
    }catch{
        print("ERROR:: Generating data from JSON Body : \(error) ")
    }

    // 2. Setting up the required Header Fields
    urlRequest.httpBody = requestData
    urlRequest.addValue("\(requestData.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    // 3. Creating the Session
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let dataTask: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
        data, response, error in

        if (error != nil){
            print("Error is: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "None")")
            return
        }

        let resp = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(data, resp?.statusCode ?? 0, error?.localizedDescription ?? "None")
        }

    })

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Problem is getting "Bad Request, 400 Status, Request must specify image and features.".

I've Checked the Request body for `isValidJSONObject`, getting true. API is working fine on Postman.
Please let me know if i am missing something, Any Help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'r sending different array for "image" and "features".

As per the Documentation request body should be as follow,

```
func getPOSTBody(base64: String) -> [String: Any]{

   let json: [String: Any] = [
     "requests": ["image": ["content": base64],
                 "features": [["type": "TEXT_DETECTION"]]
                  ]
    ]

   return json
}
```